# mysql dynamic sql using IN

Tags: mysql, sql, dynamic

I would like to create a sp with the next code:

```
select *
from document
where cod_emp='AAA'
and cod_situation in ('01','02','03');
```

But I would like ('01','02','03') to be a parameter, so I thought something like this would work:

```
-- sp's call

call sp('"01","02","03"');

-- sp's parameter

in param_txt_cod_situation text;

-- sp's code

set @cons1=
'select *
from document
where cod_emp="AAA" ';

if length(param_txt_cod_situation)>0 then
set @param_txt_cod_situation=param_txt_cod_situation;
set @cons2='and cod_situacion in concat("(",?,")") '
else
set @param_txt_cod_situation=true;
set @cons2='and ?';
end if;

set @cons=concat(
@cons1,
@cons2);

prepare cons from @cons;
execute cons using
@param_txt_cod_situation;
deallocate prepare cons;
```

But it didn't work.

Hope you guys can help me.
Thanks very much.

Comment: What doesn't work? Does it not work as you have intended or is an error being thrown?

Comment: I get an error. I thought it will be simple like using LIKE: and cod_situacion LIKE concat("%",?,"%")

Comment: The problem is CONCAT is returning a string, but in requires a list. You should just concatenate your parameters in the procedure, not in the actual query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `concat` function returns a string in whatever query it is in. You do not want to see if something is in a string but rather a list.

Replace

```
set @cons2='and cod_situacion in concat("(",?,")") '
```

with

```
set @cons2=concat('and cod_situacion in (',?,') ')
```

and see if that works

Comment: It worked! thanks very much for your help. But instead of using "?" i used the parameter directly.